# Database for work functions for exotic crystallographic faces

Tags: solid-state-physics, photoelectric-effect

Is there a database, which holds work functions (found either from experiment or calculations) for some more exotic crystallographic faces, such as (221) or (311) for copper? I dug around and found articles for the standard faces (100), (110), (111), (112) and found the same data in the springer materials database, but nothing for other faces.

Comment: Any database would be taking values from published papers, most likely. So, a search on Web of Science or your favorite local search engine might be more likely to have results. You might also look for papers on work functions for vicinal surfaces (for example this brings up a paper on angle-resolved photoemission from Cu(610) - M. Hengsberger et al., Surf. Sci. Lett 405, L491-L496 (1998)). Surface reconstructions may have a large impact on work functions as well. I'm also not sure what the funding mechanism would be to measure all Cu surfaces...